# HIVE- Aggregate function in subquery in where clause

Tags: hive

I have a requirement where I need only latest records for particular column.
I want to write something similar to below query:

```
select * from content_details c where c.created_date = (select max(created_date) from content_details where content_url=c.content_url);
```

Below query fails in Hive, what is the other way to do this?

Comment: Can you also add error in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Using join:

```
select c.* 
  from content_details c
       inner join (select content_url, 
                          max(created_date) max_created_date 
                     from content_details 
                    group by content_url
                  ) s on s.content_url=c.content_url and c.created_date=s.max_created_date
```

Using Rank() analytic function:

```
select * from
(
select c.*, rank() over(partition by content_url order by created_date desc) rnk 
  from content_details c 
)s
where rnk=1;
```